# Where does mkinitcpio save its output?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, ramdisk

When you run something like `mkinitcpio -p linux`, where is the resulting file saved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mkinitcpio's option `-p` stands for "preset". Therefore, the settings used when you give `-p linux` are defined in the file **[`/etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset`](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/plain/trunk/linux.preset?h=packages/linux)**:

```
…
default_image="/boot/initramfs-linux.img"
…
fallback_image="/boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img"
…
```

This happens to be documented in the *mkinitcpio(8)* manual page:

> `-p, --preset preset`
>
> Build initramfs image(s) according to specified preset. This may be a file in
>   /etc/mkinitcpio.d (without the .preset extension) or a full, absolute path to a file.

Answer (score -1):

The -g or --generate *filename* arguments are used to indicate mkinitcpio to generate a CPIO image as *filename*.

Comment: What if the g option is not used?

Comment: If -g is not provided nothing will be written to the filesystem.